# Aws SQS giving different messages for the same parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, message, message-queue, messaging, amazon-sqs

Aws SQS giving different messages for the same parameters

So I posted a message using:

```
https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Otherinfo/?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Ola&MessageAttribute.1.Name=test1&MessageAttribute.1.Value.StringValue=Drizzy&MessageAttribute.1.Value.DataType=String
```

The important thing here is I want to get the messages based on their attributes. Then using postman I call for Receive:

```
https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Otherinfo/?Action=ReceiveMessage&MessageAttributeName.1=test1.*&WaitTimeSeconds=10
```

I even made it wait for response but then I keep getting different messages from the queue sometimes even when I make a mistake and enter a wrong attribute name I still get a response. I'm I doing something wrong here?
Is there any other messaging system like this that would work with `AngularJS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, it sounds like you are trying to filter the messages received based on your attribute parameters - that is not how they work.

The attribute parameters is a way of specifying which attributes of the selected records should be returned - it does not apply a filter to the messages and only return the messages that match.

You can't filter messages received - you ask for messages, SQS sends you messages - you can't control the order that you get them, or the selection criteria.

Comment: Is the only way to get messages based on attribute to create new queues? So I'll have a new queue for each user-to-user interaction? And for that I'll need to enable signature 4 version signing which is very complex?

Comment: You can either have a queue per message type/class, or else have a message consumer that can parcel out the messages to the appropriate message processing service after downloading it and determining its type. Depending on your application, either method could be appropriate.

Comment: I'm testing it now and even when using the long polling with no attributes, I got only one message when they're seven in the queue, if I were to go with the message consumer, wouldn't it still be problematic. Even if I were to go with creating new queues it would be the same, is SQS just not reliable enough?

Comment: Receive message request will only send "upto" 10 messages. If you only have a handful of test messages, this is pretty normal to recieve less than 10. If you had thousands of messages in the queue, chances are you would get 10 each time. SQS is very reliable. Your application should care how many it gets at once; it should just process what it gets and then ask for more.

Comment: I understand although, if I'm using a message consumer(I'll be grateful if you name some), it needs all the messages in the queue to sort them out for me hence the dilemma. Having to constantly ask will ramp up api calls and cost.

Comment: @Olli check your messages in flight counts.  If you receive a message and leave it in flight (without resetting the visibility timeout), it's still in the queue but you cannot receive it again right away.  SQS is very reliable and not at all as sketchy as you are perceiving it to be and these sound like they may at least in part be side effects of your test methodology.  Send 10 messages to an idle queue and ask for 10 with a wait timeout, and you will usually get most if not all of them, immediately.  You will not have to ask repeatedly.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot & E.J.  I've seen the sqs documentation that says maximum 10 messages retrieved, is there another service aws offers that I can use to retrieve more messages or filter for client use and integration with sns for a messaging app?

Comment: kinesis would work for you, but it maybe a bit more work on your end to get it setup. Nice thing about SQS is that it is dead simple to use.